# Aplicar css en contenido php

Tags: php, css, html5

He generado mediante PHP una matriz en un documento. El estilo css está mediante link en el head
pero solo se aplica al body y no se por qué. Los elementos creados con el php no cogen el estilo.
Sin embargo, he probado a generar una etiqueta  dentro del body y ahi sí que me coge el estilo.
¿Quiere esto decir que para cada elemento generado con php tengo que crear una etiqueta , y no vale una hoja de estilo linkeada?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabla.css"> <!-- Esto no me lo reconoce php -->
        <title>Tabla</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>Tabla</h1>
         <table>
            <?php

                 function generarTableroHTML() {

                 $filas = 20;
                 $columnas = 20;
                 $lado = 30;

                for ( $f = 0; $f < $filas; $f++) {
                        echo `<tr>`;
                   for ($c = 0; $c < $columnas; $c++) {
         
                        echo "<td style= width: $lado px ;height:$lado px>$f-$c</td>";
        
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                  }
                }
              generarTableroHTML();
            ?>
      </table>
  </body>
```

El css es el siguiente:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  table {
      width: 60%;
      text-align: center;
      background: rgb(126, 125, 125);
      border: solid 1px #dddddd;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
   
    table tr ,
    table tr td {
      padding: 0.5625em 0.625em;
      font-size: 0.575em;
      color: #222222;
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }
    
    table tr.even,
    table tr.alt,
    table tr:nth-of-type(even) {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema. El link del archivo .css se pone en el head y por lo general va destinado a lo que pondrás en el body o en el footer. Por otra parte, no entiendo qué tiene que ver PHP en todo esto. Pon el .css directamente en el head y punto.

Comment: Te falta entrecomillar el estilo: `echo "<td style='width: $lado px ;height:$lado px'>$f-$c</td>";`. Si vas a declarar la función para llamarla inmediatamente y no la llamas otra vez, mejor no la declares y sólo ejecuta el código de la función. Por otro lado tienes un `echo` con backticks `\`\``, usa comillas simples o dobles.

Comment: @A. Cedano Creo que me expliqué mal. El <link> que hay en el head funciona correctamente. Hago una puntualización. Funciona correctamente en todo el documento menos en aquellos elementos generados en el bloque php(en este caso los tr y td). Creo que se debe a tema caché. Voy a borrar y a ver que pasa.

Comment: Esto es contradictorio en sí mismo: `echo "<td style= width: $lado px ;height:$lado px>$f-$c</td>";`, si estás usando un archivo `.css`, que es lo recomendado, evita poner estilos in-line. Define en el `.css` qué dimensiones deben tener los `td`, y no te ocupes de ello en el código `.php`. Si haces así, los `td` irían sólo con el contenido: `echo "<td>$f-$c</td>";` y lo demás iría en el `.css`. Esa es la práctica recomendada, aplicando el principio de separación de responsabilidades.

Comment: @A. Cedano Estoy de acuerdo, en un inicio era un ejercicio sin css para crear elementos dinamicamente con php. Posteriormente he ido añadiendo estilo y no he caído en el detalle. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radicaba en la caché. Al borrar y reiniciar, la pagina detecta correctamente la etiqueta con el documento css. Me ha pasado en 2 ejercicios diferentes y en ambos se solucionó borrando la caché.